# Changing google test framework default print pattern

Tags: c++11, googletest

Google test framework default print

```
 [==========] Running 4 tests from 1 test case.   
 [----------] Global test environment set-up.   
 [----------] 4 tests from gcc_tests   
 [ RUN      ]gcc_tests.functionality_test  
 [       OK ] gcc_tests.functionality_test (0 ms)    
 [ RUN      ] gcc_tests.functionality_test_1    
 [       OK ] gcc_tests.functionality_test_2 (0 ms)     
 [ RUN      ] gcc_tests.functionality_test_3    
 [       OK ] gcc_tests.functionality_test_3 (0 ms)    
 [ RUN      ] gcc_tests.functionality_test_4    
 [       OK ] gcc_tests.functionality_test_4(471 ms)   
 [----------] 4 tests from gcc_tests (471 ms total)  

 [----------] Global test environment tear-down   
 [==========] 4 tests from 1 test case ran. (471 ms total)    
 [  PASSED  ] 4 tests.
```

How to replace millisecond with second inside the bracket as shown above.

And if time will be more than 60 seconds then it should be replaced with minute.
For example, as shown in bracket 471 ms, it should be replaced with 0.475 second and if time is 76 second.
It should be replaced with 1 minute 16 second.

Comment: I am aware this does not help to solve your issue: but Unit Test should be fast - all tests should run within seconds - so you can run UT and have feedback from UT on every single change you made - otherwise these tests have very low value. So avoid single test longer than 1s...

Answer (score 3):

I can think of two ways to achieve the desired behaviour:

1. Use the [event listener API](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#extending-google-test-by-handling-test-events) to customize the output.

> Google Test provides an event listener API to let you receive notifications about the progress of a test program and test failures. The events you can listen to include the start and end of the test program, a test case, or a test method, among others. You may use this API to augment or replace the standard console output, replace the XML output, or provide a completely different form of output, such as a GUI or a database. You can also use test events as checkpoints to implement a resource leak checker, for example.

2. Use XML output so you can later post-process the results and get time values formatted at your will.